# Chrome CPU consumption alert script

Tags: macos, google-chrome, cpu

Sometimes a website on Chrome sneaks on me, and starts consuming >100% CPU continuously.
I only notice that when the fan is running full speed.

Then I use the Chrome Task manager to find the culprit and shut it down.
I do not want to investigate why some websites do that, just shut them down.

Question:

Is there a script or something, that would alert me if:
Chrome reports CPU usage >50% for a Tab for longer than a **minute**. (not for seconds, since most do that while loading)

Using the existing Chrome Task manager that already monitors CPU usage by Tab, would be nice, if I can just get an alert from it.
[image]

MacBook Air
OSX Sierra
Chrome Version 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Example with one website acting up !

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea on your issue, but just wanted to say - Nice to see you back :)

Comment: If you could solve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27679223/get-pid-of-chrome-tab, it would be easy using  ps -p xxx -o %cpu

Answer (score 1):

You should modify this script to your needs or check if it already solves them as-is

https://github.com/andyyoung/Process-Monitor-for-Chrome

Comment: Thank you. I already have a process monitor provided by Chrome Task Manager. My question was if it is possible to extract the information it is providing and alert me based on user setting CPU >50% time >1 minute.  I already have https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/processor-monitor/ihfhbddglfpbodgoalhmljdneofejjnd that displays total CPU usage in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something similar but couldn't find anything very useful so I wrote a bash+apple script to monitor bad tabs and kill them if they went over a cpu utilization threshold between running intervals. I can add to its functionality and portability or make something for the non-terminal people among us if there is any community interest. Here is the very simple first pass I use.

https://github.com/mdupuy/chromeTabMonitor